# Teams Graph API : adding a team member not always working

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I want to join a public team.  Let's call it **Experiment**.

Using the Microsoft Graph API from my WPF app, I add myself to Experiment by calling (with proper content):

```
POST /groups/{id}/members/$ref
```

It seems to work. The webrequest returns success, and when I query my joined teams (GET /me/joinedTeams), I can see Experiment in the list.

Unfortunately, when I launch the Teams desktop app (Windows), or the web client, I don't see Experiment inside the list on the left.  Even worse, when trying to join the team directly from the app, I can't find Experiment when searching for it.

The only workaround I found is to ask another member to invite me to Experiment.

Comment: Are you trying to add members for existing or newly created team? Also please provide Tenant Id and Team ID which you are trying.

Comment: This is an existing team.  That's very strange.  When calling (/me/joinedTeams), it lists 4 teams, with proper Id/name/description.  But inside the actual Teams app, I only see three teams. (**Tenant Id** : 7ba8d2fb-4660-4a19-802e-4d015a17e167), (**Team Id** : 29482241-1294-4a33-ba03-48fe9650b4db)

Comment: Are you trying these API calls on Beta or V1 endpoint? Could you please share the requestId for failed case on Beta endpoint.

Comment: I use V1 endpoint for all calls regarding users (/users/...) and I use the Beta endpoint for all calls regarding Teams.  Here are the one I use: {beta}/me/joinedTeams,   {beta}/groups/{teamid}/members/$ref, 
  {beta}/teams/{teamid}/channels/{channelid}/chatthreads

Comment: @BriocheBro - see https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/teams_api_overview#membership-changes-in-microsoft-teams for more information on the latency differences between the beta and v1 APIs. Very likely that's what's happening.

Comment: I don't know what happened in the Teams servers.  I got successfully added to my Experiment team after 12 hours.  Since then, I am able to leave the team from the Desktop app, and then successfully join the team from my Graph API code.  I tried it 4 times.  3 out of 4 were immediate, and one took a minute or two.